# Improve speed of getting conditional data from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i notice about an idea now , i want create an API  with Node

imagine we have an endpoint `GET` for gets all tickets with filter which are expired

```
endpoint =>  GET v1/tickets?expire=true
```

i want have best practice for speed and performance , usually we use some ORM condition for get filters data ( here expired tickets ) , i am using Mongoose and can do like this

```
const tickets = Ticket.find( { expire: 'true' } )
```

and also we can get all tickets and implements condition programmatically with javascript ( such as `filter` method )

> NOTE: Consider we can have more conditions like (
>   `expire&updated=date&name= ...` )

i means get all Tickets

```
const tickets = Ticket.find();

if(req.query.expire) {
    tickets.filter(...);
}
```

**Remember**
i want best performance and this solutions just because i think condition in mongoDB maybe lower than filter with js , now i ask your guys is it correct and which way better ?

Comment: Did you check how long this request would take, to download all your Tickets? And how big the request is? And how often does the data in `Ticket` change?

Comment: 1 question : no idea about this , 2 question : what means how big ? 3 question : less

Comment: check it! you've gained nothing i your filtering is 10ms faster but your overall request takes twice as long. Ultimately you're proposing to download an entire DB Table to the server on every single request, just to let the server do the filtering; and throw half of that data away.

Answer (score 2):

absolutely First way better than second way , that means you must set condition for DB or ORM instead set this condition in your code because

1. you introduce more process on server
2. every request get all data and cause all data is big , you must wait more time    for get data from database